# Building a Card with Images problem with overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm currently building products from my store in my products screen, What I'm attempting to do is, create a GridView and a card for each product. I'm having problem with the overflow from the image.
What I want to look like:
[image: Suppose to look]

How it is going:
[image: How it is going]

My code for the card:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/helpers/color_select.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/product.dart';

class ProductListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductListTile(this.product);

  final Product product;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/product', arguments: product);
        },
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: [Image.network(product.images!.first)],
              ),
              Text(
                product.name,
                style: GoogleFonts.firaCode(
                    textStyle:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ),
              Text('R\$ ${product.basePrice.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                  style: GoogleFonts.firaCode(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          color: ColorSelect.cprice)))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: You dont need stack wrapping image . Remove the stack, it should work. But if you want fixed size you can use contrainedbox with minheight and maxheight if you want

Comment: Can you formulate an answer for me plz.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your **Card** Widget inside **SingleChildScrollView()** Widget :

```
SingleChildScrollView(
child:Card(),
),
```

Comment: It fixed the Overflow, but then I have to scroll to see the text, how can I fix that? I want it to be static

Comment: If you add above type of card child is image and below part (footer) like your text so you can use flutter **GridTile** Widet here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/GridTile-class.html  or you design card any other way so can go here https://material.io/components/cards/flutter#card

Answer (score 0):

There is no need Stack widget in your code. Try this:
If you want u can remove ConstrainedBox, but image size will be different according to its size.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/helpers/color_select.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual_nnananene/models/product.dart';

class ProductListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductListTile(this.product);

  final Product product;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/product', arguments: product);
        },
        child: Card(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
               ConstrainedBox(
               constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                            minHeight: 50.0,
                            maxHeight:300.0
                            ),
                child: Image.network(product.images!.first),
              ),
              Text(
                product.name,
                style: GoogleFonts.firaCode(
                    textStyle:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ),
              Text('R\$ ${product.basePrice.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                  style: GoogleFonts.firaCode(
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                          color: ColorSelect.cprice)))
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I got an overflow error on the bottom ofthe image

Comment: Then increase minHeight and maxHeight. You are giving kind of fixed height to image

Comment: But Can I make the images all the same size inside the card?

Comment: If that was possible, it would be great

Comment: u can  add parameter inside image.network -->  
          width: width,
          height: height,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,

Comment: Is there a way to make the image fill all it can? without needind to set the height and widht?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount`? If yes, it has a property `aspectRatio` which is default to 1.0 (height will be same as width). Try to make it 0.7 or something and your error will be gone in that case.

Comment: I still get a overload in the middle of the card

Comment: you can try 0.5 or something then but based on your use-case.

Comment: yep, I tried adding different values but all of then gave me overflow

Comment: Can you paste your `GridView` initialisation code? Also, Column's mainAxisSize should be min in your ProductListTile class.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the first image this way

```
Container(
decoration: Boxdecoration( 
color: Colors.white,
borderRadius: borderRadius.circular(8),
boxShasow: [
 BoxShadow(
offset: Offset(10,17),
blurRadius:17,
spreadRadius: -23,
color: Colors.grey,),],),
child: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInset.all(10.0),
child: Column(
Image.network(
"your url",
width: width of choice,
height: height of choice,
), 
Text(
"product name",
testAlign:TestAlign.left,
style:(your style),
),
Row(
children:<Widget>[
Text(
"product amount",
testAlign:TestAlign.left,
style:(your style),
),
Expanded(
child:Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
children: <Widget>[
Icon(
Icons.heart_outlind,
color:Colors.blue,
size:24,
),
SizedBox(width:5),
],),),
],),),),
```